# Questions more suitable for "Computational Science" instead of "Computer Science"

Tags: discussion, scope, migration

I noticed that there are quite some "simple" questions with the tag "numerical-analysis" or "linear-algebra", which haven got a "good" answer so far. Of course, I could try to write good answers to these questions myself. However, I have the impression that the better idea would be to leave a comment that the [Computational Science](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com) stack-exchange site might be able to come up with better answers. (This doesn't necessarily apply to all questions with these tags, but if a question starts to involve the tradeoff between robustness, accuracy and speed, then "scientific computing" experts really might come up with better answers.)

I don't think that migrating old questions would be a good idea, but I wonder whether it could make sense to migrate such questions more actively in the future.

Comment: Do you have examples of questions that you consider off-topic? We don't appear to have ever migrated a question to [scicomp.se]. Note that we would only migrate a question if it's off-topic, or at least borderline and strongly better suited to the other site. If a question happens to be on-topic on two sites, it normally stays on the site where the asker chose to post it.

Comment: @Gilles I don't think that these questions are off-topic here. However, some of these "simple" questions haven't even managed to attract a single comment, leave alone an answer (and hence also no "good" answer). If the same question would be asked on the mathematics stackexchange site or the computational sciences (="scientific computing") stackexchange site, it would have received at least enough attention for a comment or an answer. The answers between the two sites would be quite different, but at least they would try to answer the question in a certain sense.

Comment: We can at least point people to [scicomp.se] if warranted, and even suggest a migration if the asker desires and there haven't been any good answers yet. The guideline is to suggest a better site (in case the user wasn't aware of that other site) without imposing it (especially if there are good answers already that are in the style of the original site).

Comment: Related: [What's exactly the difference between Computer Science and Computational Science in SE?](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/589/whats-exactly-the-difference-between-computer-science-and-computational-science)